# Can RMI or CORBA operate over IP?

Tags: programming-languages, ip-address

Question: **Can RMI or CORBA operate over IP?**

*I don't think RMI can - does it not operate over IIOP?*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RMI -> IIOP -> IP.

CORBA -> IIOP -> IP.

Comment: So RMI and CORBA both run over IIOP through IP?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Inter-Orb_Protocol and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI-IIOP

Comment: RMI can also run over JRMP.